# More elegant way to repeat and join a known string an unknown number of times

Tags: java, java-8

My goal is to join a known string using a delimiter an unknown number of times.

So if I know that the string is `?` and the delimiter is `,` and I know I want it repeated `5` times I would get `?,?,?,?,?`

This code will do that:

```
int n = 5;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) al.add("?");
String s = String.join(",", al);
```

But that is so verbose.  Am I missing something in the Java 8 libraries? No additional dependencies please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not new in Java 8, but you can use [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) to create a `List` that you can pass to `String.join`.  It has been around since the Collections API was created in Java 1.2.

```
String s = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(5, "?"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Without materializing a `Collection` (and parallelizes better than the generate/limit example):

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(i -> "?").collect(joining(","));
```

Comment: My [benchmarking results](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/d4dce638197fe34987e3) are somewhat dubious: for `n = 10000` limit version outperforms the range version, but for `n = 1000000` range wins. Note that for the best performance in parallel you need to explicitly specify the `unordered()` (which is not necessary in limit version). And if somebody really cares about performance, it's possible to craft a sequential solution which is in order of magnitude faster (see baseline test, it would be even faster using unsafe String creation).

Comment: @TagirValeev Looking at the specs again, that's because `generate()` generates an unordered stream, and the usual deficiencies of `limit()` (which usually render it a disaster in parallel) are mitigated by the unordered-ness.  So the two sort of canceled each other out.

Comment: Is it really that hard to implement pipeline stages which understand if the previous stage is infinite (which implies that limit() will turn them into a perfectly SIZED stream)? To me it looks like an oversight similar to not use the SIZED property when `count()` is called…

Comment: @Holger You would need a stream flag for KNOWN_INFINITE; just looking at the previous stage is not enough.  Such a flag was considered.  (Essentially, this would only exist to improve limit().)

Comment: @Brian Goetz: that’s what I meant, flags aka characteristics. But each stage may modify them, e.g. a `limit()` turns the hypothetical `KNOWN_INFINITE` into `SIZED`. When it was considered, why was it dropped? It doesn’t seem to impose huge costs on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A Stream-based solution, just for completeness:

```
String s = Stream.generate(() -> "?").limit(5).collect(joining(","));
```

If performance is required, it's possible to manually craft a much faster (up to 10x) solution:

```
public static String nCopies(String symbol, String delimiter, int count) {
    if(count <= 0) return "";
    char[] result = new char[(symbol.length()+delimiter.length())*count-delimiter.length()];
    fill(result, symbol, delimiter, count);
    return new String(result);
}

private static void fill(char[] result, String symbol, String delimiter, int count) {
    if(count == 1) {
        symbol.getChars(0, symbol.length(), result, 0);
        return;
    }
    int half = count/2;
    int filled = (symbol.length()+delimiter.length())*half-delimiter.length();
    if(count % 2 == 0) {
        fill(result, symbol, delimiter, half);
        delimiter.getChars(0, delimiter.length(), result, filled);
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, result, filled+delimiter.length(), filled);
        return;
    }
    fill(result, symbol, delimiter, half);
    int offset = filled;
    delimiter.getChars(0, delimiter.length(), result, offset);
    offset+=delimiter.length();
    symbol.getChars(0, symbol.length(), result, offset);
    offset+=symbol.length();
    delimiter.getChars(0, delimiter.length(), result, offset);
    offset+=delimiter.length();
    System.arraycopy(result, 0, result, offset, filled);
}
```

Usage:

```
String s = nCopies("?", ",", 5);
```

Comment: I would like to see this as one of the signatures for `String.join` in a future jdk.